# I don't understand how the KL Divergence works for the stated goal of Inception Score

Tags: kl-divergence, inception

Inception Score has two goals:

- The entropy for the distribution prediced on individual samples should be small(the outputs are specific)
- The entropy for the marginal distribution over all samples should be large (the output labels should be balanced)

I understand that this is one reasonable outcome of optimizing for the KL Divergence. But can't I get the opposite as well if I just optimize for that, e.g.

- The entropy of the predicted distribution for individual samples is high (the individual samples looks like nothing in particular)
- The entropy ot the marginal distribution is large (the generator mostly outputs the same class)

It seems to me that this second outcome is just as likely when just looking at the divergence between the two distributions. Are there any practical constraints that prevent this from happening?